# Where + block - not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

User has many accounts, Account has one role. I need to check that at least one of Accounts has a role with a condition set to true:

`@current_user.accounts.where { |x| x.role.some_condition? }.exists?`

But `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Even this doesn't work

```
@current_user.accounts.where { |x| true } # the same error
@current_user.accounts.where(true) # ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using `Enumerable#any?`:

```
@current_user.accounts.any? { |x| x.role.some_condition? }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `any?` as the selected answer points out. But that will load all your accounts and **then** filter them.

The following is what you want if the condition is a flag set in the roles table.

```
@current_user.
accounts.
joins(:role).
where(roles: {some_column_in_roles_table: true}).
group("accounts.id").
exists?
```